# How to compare the slope of lines from different charts?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm plotting stock market charts with matplotlib in Python, where the x-axis represents dates with 0-indexed numbers, and the y-axis shows varying price scales for different stocks.

I draw lines between 2 points of varying lengths on each of these charts and calculated their slope.

$$ m = \frac{{y2 - y1}\text{ }(\Delta y)}{{x2 - x1}\text{ }(\Delta x)} $$

**I want to filter out charts with slope values less than -1.1**

However lines with identical slopes can look very different on various charts.

The way i understand the slope formula, for every change in `x`, `y` moves `N` points.

With this understanding, I tried normalizing the slope by using a constant value for `change in x` ($ \Delta x $), lets say 10

$$ 
\text{Normalized }\Delta x = \frac{\Delta x}{10}
$$

$$
\text{Normalized }m = \frac{\Delta y}{\text{Normalized }\Delta x}
$$

I read the above as `For every 10 point change in x, y moves N points.`

Now i can use this `Normalized slope` to compare lines from different charts.

**Is my thought process and calculation correct?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).